# What is the difference between these two types of data struct?

Tags: struct

Can anyone tell me what the difference between these two types of data structures is? The first one uses TAG "worker". In the second one I declared the names in the data structure itself "rober" and "zzymon". As for me, the first one is more practical to use...

```
// FIRST structure TAG**
struct worker
{
    int age1;
    char *hair_color1;
};

struct worker grzegorz;
grzegorz.age1 = 15;
grzegorz.hair_color1 = "gray";

struct worker krzys;
krzys.age1 = 26;
krzys.hair_color1 = "white";

// SECOND structure variables struct type**
struct
{
    int age2;
    char *hair_color2;
}
robert, szymon;

robert.age2 = 12;
robert.hair_color2 = "blond";

szymon.age2 = 14;
szymon.hair_color2 = "gray";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one defines a struct type `struct worker` and then later defines two instances of that struct type `grzgorz` and `krzys`.

The second one defines two instances of an anonymous struct type called `robert` and `szymon`

In both cases, you get two objects of the same struct type you can do things with.  In the first case, that struct type also has a name, so you can later define other things with the same type (or pointers to that type, etc), while in the second case you cannot, as the struct type is anonymous.